# 2TB NAS HDD Power Supply Recommendations

Tags: hard-disk, server, nas, sata

I'm building a custom NAS as a backup server for multiple laptops in my house. I'm planning on buying four 2TB mechanical SATA hard drives that will be run in RAID 1

(Hard drives: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822236342&ignorebbr=1)

The drives will be going in this case here: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA00Y50Z9087&ignorebbr=1

The case has 4 SATA cable connectors that will be connected to a SATA cable to USB adapter and they will be connected to my logic boards USB ports.

My question for all of you is what power supply would you recommend to power ONLY the hard drives. This power supply will not be powering my logic board. I want to make sure that I won't fry a hard drive, but I also want to make sure that the power supply has enough wattage for expansion in the future (should I need use bigger hard drives / SSDs).

**IMPORTANT POINTS**

1. The hard drives must be powered by a power supply independent from my logic board.
2. The hard drives SATA data cables must be connected to USB.
3. Because the SATA data cables are not connected to the logic board, the power supply must provide at least 2 SATA Power Connector cables.
4. I'm shooting in the ballpark of no more than $150.

*Note: I know this is a weird build and I understand the bottleneck of USB with SATA, but I want to see if this configuration is possible before completely buying all new hardware.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you done at the end? I'm just curious because I need to do the same.